# Что может сбивать работу драйвера Bluetooth на Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, драйвер, bluetooth

1. После загрузки системы, если нажать "Принимать файлы", телефонами ПК обнаруживается, но они не могут отправить файлы. Если этот же USB Bluetooth запустить на VM (проброс USB), то там после загрузки системы после 1-го раза
2. Если загрузиться с другого ПЗУ, с очень похоими установками, то там всём ОК.
3. Методы устранения ситуации напоминают. поиски капелек ртути. Надо перерывать и перекопать и переустановить и ресетнуть всё чтобы это найти. Тогда стиль передачи по WiFi напоминает об ресете, на него перейти нельзя.